# All functionalities are not working in program run via .desktop file icon

Tags: python, icons, pyside, fedora, scapy

I have written a code in python with two functionality (say A and B). When I run these program through terminal, it works perfectly fine. Python codes include scapy module and PySide GUI.
Now, I wanted an icon which will run the same program automatically, so I wrote a .desktop file.
.desktop file is shown below.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Covert Channel - Detection
Exec=python /root/Documents/path-to-code/detection.py
Icon=/root/Downloads/index.jpg
Terminal=false
```

Now, the problem is, out of two functionality A and B, only A is working.
My friend has to same problem with some different code (in different language)

Note: Working OS is Fedora 20 32-bits in VMWare and I am logged in as root.

Comment: Do you need to set a working directory? From which directory do you run the program when using the terminal?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you. But the code is in /root/Documents/path-to-code/ directory. While running through terminal, i execute python /root/Documents/path-to-code/detection.py. In .desktop file, I specific the command.
Exec=python /root/Documents/path-to-code/detection.py

Comment: It could make a difference if the current directory is /`root/docs/path-to-code` and then you do `python /root/docs/path-to-code/detection.py` or if the current directory is something else and you run the same command.

Comment: I checked the directory. It's correct. But still if i am missing something. Please do elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(using answer instead of comment to use nicer formatting)

This can be due to wrong working directories. Consider the following example:

```
testfile = open("testfile.txt", 'w')
testfile.write("TEST")
testfile.close()
```

stored in the file `/tmp/subdir/test.py`. If I now open a terminal and do the following:

```
cd /tmp/subdir
python /tmp/subdir/test.py
```

the `testfile.txt` is created in `/tmp/subdir`. But I can also do

```
cd /tmp
python /tmp/subdir/test.py
```

and `testfile.txt` will be created in `/tmp`, because it is the current working directory. You can even call `python /tmp/subdir/test.py` from your home directory, and the `testfile.txt` will be created there. It is now possible that "functionality A" works with any current working directory (cwd) and "functionality B" requires the cwd to be for example `/root/Documents/path-to-code/`.

Perhaps https://askubuntu.com/questions/50085/setting-the-working-directory might help.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I didn't write a complete address of a file.